# Running NodeJS as a service in Windows with child process

Tags: node.js, windows-services

I've got two NodeJS servers running on Windows, one listening for incoming requests which then shapes the request and then hands the request off to a worker server. The worker server will take the inputs from the controller and perform several functions: log the event with the DB, shell out to perform an action through a child process, evaluate the results and finally return the results back to the controller.

When I run both processes through Powershell or cmd everything runs fine. If I run the Controller as a service with NSSM and the Worker on Powershell everything works fine. However, if I run the Worker server as a service with NSSM the child processes fail (console.logs or using something like bunyon seem to be swallowed up so debugging is difficult). Is there any way to run NodeJS as a server if it needs to execute child processes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can try redirecting the `stdout` and `stderr` stream of the worker using

```
var fs = require('fs'),
     spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
     out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
     err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

 var child = spawn('prg', [], {
   detached: true,
   stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
 });

 child.unref();
```

This way while spawning, we are giving an `fd` to the worker process to write the output to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I attempted use something like this but there was data going to stdin and stdout and I wasn't able to successfully implement your suggestion. I ended up having to host Node in IIS with iisnode, which allowed the child processes to execute properly and all stdout captured just when running from the command line. Thank you for your suggestion.